# How to fix: 'TypeError: entities is not iterable' in ngRx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

***How to fix: 'TypeError: entities is not iterable' in
    ngRx: Please Let me known if someone get that.***

**//users.action**

```js
        import { Course } from '../model/user';
        import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
        import { Update } from '@ngrx/entity';

        export const loadCourses = createAction(
          '[Courses List] Load Courses via Service'
        );

        export const coursesLoaded = createAction(
          '[Courses Effect] Courses Loaded Successfully',
          props<{ courses: Course[] }>()
        );

        export const createCourse = createAction(
          '[Create Course Component] Create Course',
          props<{ course: Course }>()
        );

        export const deleteCourse = createAction(
          '[Courses List Operations] Delete Course',
          props<{ courseId: string }>()
        );

        export const updateCourse = createAction(
          '[Courses List Operations] Update Course',
          props<{ update: Update<Course> }>()
        );

        export const courseActionTypes = {
          loadCourses,
          coursesLoaded,
          createCourse,
          deleteCourse,
          updateCourse,
        };
```

**//reducers -> user.ts**

```js
        import { Course } from '../model/user';
        import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
        import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
        import { courseActionTypes, coursesLoaded } from '../action/user';

        export interface State extends EntityState<Course> {
          coursesLoaded: boolean;
        }

        export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Course> = createEntityAdapter<Course>();

        export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
          coursesLoaded: false,
        });

        export const courseReducer = createReducer(
          initialState,
          on(courseActionTypes.coursesLoaded, (state, { courses }) => {
            alert('hellobc');
            // the problem is here
            return adapter.addAll(courses, state);
          })

          // on(courseActionTypes.createCourse, (state, action) => {
          //   return adapter.addOne(action.course, state);
          // }),

          // on(courseActionTypes.deleteCourse, (state, action) => {
          //   return adapter.removeOne(action.courseId, state);
          // }),

          // on(courseActionTypes.updateCourse, (state, action) => {
          //   return adapter.updateOne(action.update, state);
          // })
        );
        export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
          return courseReducer(state, action);
        }

        export const { selectAll, selectIds } = adapter.getSelectors();
```

**//SELECTOR -> user.selector.ts**

```js
        import { State } from '../store/reducers/user';
        import { Course } from './../store/model/user';
        import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
        import { selectAll, selectIds } from '../store/reducers/user';

        export const courseFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<State>('courses');

        export const getAllCourses = createSelector(courseFeatureSelector, selectAll);

        export const areCoursesLoaded = createSelector(
          courseFeatureSelector,
          (state) => state.coursesLoaded
        );
```

**//state --> app.state.module.ts**

```js
        import { Course } from './store/model/user';
        export interface AppState {
          readonly courses: Course[];
        }
```

**//effects -> user.effect.ts**

```js
        import {
          courseActionTypes,
          coursesLoaded,
          updateCourse,
        } from '../store/action/user';
        import { UserServices } from '../services/user';
        import { createEffect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
        import { concatMap, map, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';

        @Injectable()
        export class CourseEffects {
          loadCourses$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$.pipe(
              ofType(courseActionTypes.loadCourses),
              switchMap(() => this.courseService.AllUser()),
              map((courses) => courseActionTypes.coursesLoaded({ courses }))
            )
          );

          constructor(private courseService: UserServices, private actions$: Actions) {}
        }
```

**//app.module.ts**

```js
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

        import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
        import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
        import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
        import { CreateuserComponent } from './createuser/createuser.component';
        import { UpdateuserComponent } from './updateuser/updateuser.component';
        import { reducer } from './store/reducers/user';
        import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
        import { CourseEffects } from './effects/user';
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            NavigationComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            CreateuserComponent,
            UpdateuserComponent,
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot({ courses: reducer }),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([CourseEffects]),
            HttpClientModule,
          ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent],
        })
        export class AppModule {}
```

**//home.component.ts**

```js
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import * as user_action from '../store/action/user';
        import { Course } from '../store/model/user';
        import { AppState } from '../app-state.module';
        import { getAllCourses } from '../selector/user.selector';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-home',
          templateUrl: './home.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
        })
        export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
          public users$: Observable<Course[]>;
          constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

          ngOnInit() {
            this.users$ = this.store.select(getAllCourses);
            this.users$.subscribe((data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });

            this.store.dispatch(user_action.loadCourses());
          }
        }
```

Comment: That’s a lot of code.. it seems the error relates to you somewhere in your code trying to itterate (loop) through an entity, which is an object. In order to loop, you need an array.

Comment: happens to me as well

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue, and it was really silly, I had large amount of actions (start,success,error)
I repeated the same string literals action by mistake

It conflicts with the start action (same name)

```js
export const searchForAdvertisesSuccess = createAction(
    '[Advertise/API/Home] Search For Advertise', // <--
    props<{ result: IGroupedAdvertises[] }>()
);
```

See? I had to add Success after that string

```js
export const searchForAdvertisesSuccess = createAction(
    '[Advertise/API/Home] Search For Advertise Success', // <--
    props<{ result: IGroupedAdvertises[] }>()
);
```

Thought it may help anyone

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `courses` in `courseActionTypes.coursesLoaded` after the effect isn't an array.

I would recommend you to check the effect or to share code of `courseService.AllUser`.

```js
    switchMap(() => this.courseService.AllUser()),
    // check here what switchMap returns
    tap(console.log),
    map((courses) => courseActionTypes.coursesLoaded({ courses }))
```

I bet the problem is here.

Comment: I had the same error message. For me it was because I had confused `find` with `findOne` in the backend. So I didn't get an array, but exactly one element.